# Adding a loader after clicking submit button on a form (loader keeps repeating)

Tags: javascript, jquery

My goal is to replace the form submission button with an image loader after click so that when an uploaded image is loading, the user won't just look at a blank screen. I achieved this, however it is not ideal.

I feel as though I'm doing something poorly because the loader is acting strange, sometimes it will show only once but others it gets repeated, and `background-repeat: no-repeat` has no effect.

Here is my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("input[name='application-submit']").hover(function() {
      $(this).toggleClass("btn-hover");
      $("form").submit(function() {
         $("input[name='application-submit']").after('<img src="img/loader.GIF" alt="Swole Inc Loader" class="loader">');
         $("input[name='application-submit']").hide();
         $("img.loader").css("position", "relative", "top", "0", "left", "0");
      });
   });
});
```

Am I doing something wrong here that is making it so that the CSS I'm using is ineffective? Is my method archaic? What is a more efficient way to go about this? (I don't want the full code, I just need to be steered in the right direction as to what I'm doing wrong).

You can see a live example [here](https://www.swoleinc.com/#apply). If you upload an image and then click submit (ignore the other fields), you'll see the image loader in question.

Comment: is there a functional issue here... or you are just asking is there a better way to do it

Comment: The question states that there is a functional issue (the repeat of the loader) as well as asks for a more efficient way of implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is on every click you are adding a new image, also you are adding multiple submit handlers

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $btn = $("input[name='application-submit']").hover(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("btn-hover");
    });
    $("form").submit(function () {
        var $img = $btn.next('.loader').show();
        if (!$img.length) {
            $img = $('<img src="img/loader.GIF" alt="Swole Inc Loader" class="loader">').css({
                position: 'relative',
                top: 0,
                left: 0
            }).insertAfter($btn);
        }
        $btn.hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: Ah, I see what I was doing now. Thank you! Can you explain the !$img.length part? Is that saying if the image does not exceed the width of the image then add it, meaning there is nothing there yet, and if so, add nothing?

Comment: @LansanaCamara yes... if the image does not exists then add it else just show the existing one