# I want to show loading gif after clicking form submit button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, codeigniter

I want to show a loading gif after submit button click. 
what changes I need to do thanks.
 the problem is when student enter seat number they click submit but in response to the result server take 4 to 5 sec in that time interval student presses button multiple time and server receive the unwanted request

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function check()
 {   
var candidateid = document.getElementById("candidateid").value;
 if(candidateid=='') 
{
 $('.candidateid').toggle("show");
setTimeout(function() 
{ 
 $(".candidateid").toggle("hide");
}, 3000);
return false;
} 
return true;   
}   
</script>
```

```html
 <html>
<body>
<!-- Contact Us -->
<section id="contact" class="contact section">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="section-title">
<h2><span>Manthan</span> Talent Search Exam <?php echo date('Y')?></h2>
<p>विद्यार्थ्यांना देण्यात आलेल्या हॉलतिकीट वरील Student ID वरील रकान्यात भरून Submit वर क्लिक करा</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="contact-head">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-12">
      
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-12">
<div class="form-head">
<!-- Form -->
<form class="form" action="<?php echo ('https://www.manthanpublication.com/view_result/')?>" method="POST" autocomplete="off" onsubmit="return check();">
<div class="form-group">
<input id="candidateid" name="candidateid" type="number" placeholder="Enter Candidate Id">
</div>
<p class="candidateid" style="display:none; color:red;"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Enter Candidate Id</p>
<div class="form-group">
<div class="button">
<button  name="submit" type="submit"  class="btn primary">Submit</button>
      
</div>

</div>
        
</form>
<!--/ End Form -->
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
   
</div>
</section>
<!--/ End Contact Us --> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding a loader after clicking submit button on a form (loader keeps repeating)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31471044/adding-a-loader-after-clicking-submit-button-on-a-form-loader-keeps-repeating)

Comment: I think that will work but don't know what changes exactly I need to do and where. please help me thanks

Comment: add your script here

Comment: uploaded the full file here please check https://www.dropbox.com/s/so67hu9zde60s9r/manthantest.php?dl=0

Comment: hello, @VigneshA  are you there please help me .please check the dropbox link for full page script thanks

Comment: please add your script here. and you have many script errors in your page . fix that and update here then we will trying to help you

Comment: @VigneshA and everyone. I have edited the question and added the script there and removed the error, please tell me what changes I need to make, thanks

Comment: hi @akash how did you save your data to the table. did you use any ajax request.

Comment: data is on MySQL table this https://manthanpublication.com/manthantest/ page only get the value and send to another page https://manthanpublication.com/view_result

Comment: so you're not making any ajax call  am i right?

Comment: yes. there is no ajax call